# How can I count every next each other checked checkbox in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, checkbox, count, checked

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jHaP.jpg)
I'm looking for more then 8h, unsuccessfully.

I would like to count checked checkbox in excel... so count every next each other checked box.
For example how many checked checkbox is in "group A", and "B"and ....(see on image) but group A and B is in the same row and between A and B is one, or more unchecked check box.
(it's possible to one row, 19, will fully with checked checkbox, and only one big checked group have).

I see the =COUNTIF and another formula can count all checked box in one row... but it's not okay for me now.

I try to explain myself with a pseudocode:
for example:

```
all counter initialized 0;
if checking box 1 = checked, counter A increase 1,
if checking box 2 = checked, counter A++
if checking box 3 = checked, counter A++
if checking box 4 = unchecked, do nothing
if checking box 5 = checked, counter B increase 1;
if checking box 6 = checked, counter B ++;
if checking box 7 = checked, counter B++;
if checking box 8 = unchecked, do nothing;
if checking box 9 = unchecked, do nothing;
if checking box 10 = checked; counter C increase 1;
if checking box 11 = checked; counter C ++;
if checking box 12 = unchecked; do nothing;
```

all checking box (1 -> 12) are in the same row, and all checking box size more then one cells... the correct answer (now) is A = 3, B = 3, C = 2, but these numbers are totally randomly... maybe next time A group have 4, the B = 7 and the C = 0; - if all checking box are unchecked in the row, reset counters.

Three counter / row will be enough, haven't more than 3 "group" in the same row. The checking box size not equal to excel cells size...

These rows are unique. And have 3 rows, but formula is the same, I think... I don't know how can I coding this in excel ?!?

Thank you so much for your helping!

Comment: Why can you not use =countif() for specific ranges?, are you counting the linked cells?

Comment: "I try wto solve this problem with IF COUNTIF COUNTIFS" please edit your question to _show_ us what you tried

Comment: I'm confused with what you are after, would the answer be 4, or rather 13?

Comment: You should show the column headers as well along with row labels. Showing what you have tried and the expected output as you desire might help to reproduce the solution with more accuracy i believe.

Comment: Don't be afraid to break the logic down into steps and build using those steps, using some space in the spreadsheet. E.g. in rows 28, 29 and 30, you can do something like B28: if(B19=1, A28+1, 0) and drag across. Then separate rows to extract the final results you want.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Okay! I edited and added additional information in my question :)